# How do I fix visual studio installer (2019 community) is empty?

Tags: visual-studio, installation, windows-10, visual-studio-2019

I downloaded the visual studio 2019 community installer and ran it. It ran successfully but instead of opening the visual studio installer when it completed it just closed. I located the visual studio installer 'setup.exe' (under C:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/Installer) and ran it. It opens the installer but instead of allowing me to select tools to install it just has 2 empty tabs labeled 'installed' and 'available' and a side bar that shows developer news.

I don't have any antivirus or firewall running. I uninstalled every version of visual studio I had in case the installer was assuming I already have VS2019. I updated windows and my drivers.

EDIT:
I had a hunch that I might find something out by using 'setup -h' in command prompt. It appears that it may be possible to install vs2019 by using the right tags.
I guessed

```
setup install --productid Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community --channelid VisualStudio.15.Release
```

might work but the installer says "
A product matching the following parameters cannot be found:
channelId: VisualStudio.15.Release
productId: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Product.Community
"

If you know what the right tags are that might be an adequate solution.

Comment: Hi cbap, any update about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Please try to reinstall it:

**1)** run cmd as **Administrator** and then type:

```
"%programfiles(x86)%\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe" -full
```

**2)** restart `vs_installer` again.

Comment: After running that command there is no file called 'vs_installer' in the program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio folder.
Running vs_community opens the thing that installs the installer and downloads successfully but then it gets stuck on installing and then it says 'unable to install the files to target location. error:the folder ~~ or a file within it is locked by another program. close any applications that might be using it and try again.
I might try again later after a reboot.

Comment: Sorry. what I meant is that vs community.exe. After run that command,  you should restart that vs community.exe. Also, after reboot, you should run the program as administrator.